# Visual studio conditional compilation for os

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cross-platform, .net-standard-2.0

I know that there is a way to conditionally compile for target frameworks eg #if net461  ....#elif ....
But is there a way to conditionally compile for specific os 
Like target _os_MAC or target_os_win

If there is can someone guide me to the documentations or tutorials to how to implement it?

Part 2:
Also , is there a way to create a custom tag so that I do not have to change every tag whenever there is a change to the new target os or framework .eg from net461 to net471

Comment: no there is not :)

Comment: And who told you that you can change .Net frame work version from code ?

Comment: @zackraiyan You've completely misunderstood the question. OP is asking about preprocessor directives.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead , where did OP mention it ? And i don't understand the term `Conditionally compile for targeted framework` , is this even possible? As far my knowledge , this can only be done during the build within the IDE , right ?Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @zackraiyan "conditionally compile" can mean anything "at compile time". Either via your IDE or via the command line compiler. Preprocessor directives exist for this purpose ... they happen _before_ compilation.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead , i know... maybe the question made stumped me for a while.....specially the `If` and `ElseIf` he included in the question .... ANyway, i guess i really misunderstood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes you're asking about custom pre-processor symbols (that is how I have interpreted it - do correct me if I am wrong.

You could use a custom build configuration:

Start by going into the build Configuration Manager..

[image: Configuration Manager]

Next, create a new build configuration. You can copy the configuration from an existing one:

[image: Create new configuration]

Then, right click on your Project and go to Properties. Under the build tab, define a conditional compilation symbol:

[image: Conditional compilation symbol]

Do the same for Windows.

Then you can write conditional steps like the below:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
#if MACOS
        Console.WriteLine("OSX");
#elif WINDOWS
        Console.WriteLine("Windows");
#endif

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Depending on your chosen build configuration .. you'll either get:

#### OSX:

[image: OSX]

#### Windows:

[image: Windows]

Comment: The idea is there. However, wouldn't i need to change the configuration whenever i change machine. I am trying to get my application  to be cross platform so it needs to be able to automatically detect it is a windows or macos machine and run the cosresponding code. Maybe there is a missing step somewhere to this solution.

Comment: Well this is all done at compile time ... you could write a build script that chooses your configuration (MSBuild `/p:Configuration`) ... or you could simply switch the build configuration (its a dropdown in Visual Studio) on your development machines.

Comment: Given you're now saying "cross platform" and "auto detect" - do you want this to happen at compile time or runtime? I'm confused about your requirements now.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. I was abit confuse about this matter but now i am clear after discussion with my team. I am trying to do this at compile time. so i guess this method will work. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is there a need for me to create 4 configurations in total?. i.e MACOS Debug/Release, Windows Debug/Release

Comment: Just a short comment to say that if you don't use Visual Studio, the answer from @Erndob might be much better to follow.

Comment: The answer from @Erndob unfortunately does not work if the conditional definitions should depend on the target OS at runtime. For instance if having a cross-platform .NET 6 application and choosing WSL as target, it still detects "Windows" as OS. Is there any solution for conditional definitions depending on the runtime OS?

Answer (score 21):

It's an old question, but if someone comes here now, there's a better option.

You do not need to have different configurations and select manually which configuration to use.

You can use System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation?view=netframework-4.8

There's a good manual here: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2018/11/05/platform-conditional-compilation-in-net-core/
Minimal info from the link:
Change your .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup> 
 <OutputType>Exe</OutputType> 
 <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework> 
 <IsWindows Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Windows)))' == 'true'">true</IsWindows> 
 <IsLinux Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Linux)))' == 'true'">true</IsLinux> 
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsWindows)'=='true'">
 <DefineConstants>Windows</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsLinux)'=='true'">
 <DefineConstants>Linux</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will conditionally define constants. Which you later use like so:

```
#if Linux
    Console.WriteLine("Built on Linux!"); 
#elif Windows
    Console.WriteLine("Built in Windows!"); 
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the link; it's still working well for .NET 6.0 (macOS & Linux at least).