# How much does forward headers middleware impact if not needed in ASP.NET Core 7.x?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a ASP.NET Core 7.x WebAPI which I run on a Windows server and a Linux (Debian DigitalOcean droplet).

On Debian it runs behind nginx so I needed to add the Forward Headers middleware in `Program.cs` like the following partial example:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
// ##### Added Configure call for ForwardedHeaders #####
builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders =
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});

var app = builder.Build();
// ###### Added call to middleware for ForwardedHeaders
app.UseForwardedHeaders();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

However the Windows box does not need that code since it isn't running behind nginx.

**Is There Any Impact?**

Is there a noticeable impact on having that middleware included on the Windows site?

**A Way To Include Code Only On Linux Build ?**

Is there a way to include this code so it is only added on a Linux build?
If so, please point me to where I can learn to do OS-dependent build via `dotnet` CL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual studio conditional compilation for os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49911281/visual-studio-conditional-compilation-for-os)

Comment: @PoulBak - I'm reading over it to see. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there any impact?**
The overhead of useing this middleware is negligible. `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers are not present in the request (like in the case of your Windows server which isn't behind a reverse proxy), the middleware will essentially be a no-op.

**A way to include Code only on Linux Build?**
I'd suggest doing it via configuration and feature flags, so that, in a configuration file `useForwardedHeaders` is set to true for Linux deployment

```cs
bool useForwardedHeaders = builder.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("UseForwardedHeaders");

if (useForwardedHeaders)
{
    app.UseForwardedHeaders();
}
```

Another approach would be to use runtime info

```cs
if (System.RuntimeInteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.Linux))
{
  app.UseForwardedHeaders();
}
```

Comment: This is great, you are answer all my questions.  Thanks very much. I will read over it again and make sure I can implement this then mark as answer if everything works.